# PyCharm, удалённый проект и окружение.

Tags: python, pycharm, django, ssh, sftp

Всем доброе время суток.

Есть удалённый проект на Django. Я настраиваю PyCharm для работы с ним по SFTP. При этом изменения в файлах отражаются на сервере (копируются при изменении).

Вопрос. Как мне читать окружение с сервера и запускать проект тоже на сервере?

Например, на сервере есть модуль, который не установлен на локальной машине. Как мне сделать, чтобы для этого модуля было автодополнение кода и чтобы не ругался на него? Можно ли сделать, чтобы PyCharm думал, что он на сервере, а не на моей машине. Так как от SFTP мне на данный момент пользы как кот наплакал (только копирование кода автоматическое).

Спасибо.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для этого существуют Remote Interpreters:

- http://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2013/03/how-pycharm-helps-you-with-remote-development/
- http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/quickstart/configuring_interpreter.html#remote_ssh

Comment: находил первую ссылку, но решил всё же спросить. Сейчас попробую сделать это.

Comment: Да, всё круто. Только не могу найти, где поставить параметр хоста.. То есть чтобы не runserver 127.0.0.1, а runserver 0.0.0.0 запускалось?